# How to disable comments from facebook share dialog box?

Tags: javascript, facebook, wordpress, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-sharer

Consider that a user visits an online news-website (nytimes, bbc, etc) and shares a story on facebook or twitter by commenting 'good' or 'bad' about it. My question is that, can news-websites (in this case nytimes, bbc, etc) control sharing the story by notify the user? If yes how they could do it? To further illustrate the problem, I want to update/cutomize FB.ui with ': ' in the following code. I don't know work around with this.

```
FB.ui(
{
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
    name: 'something here',
    link: 'http://www.example.com/' + username,
    caption: 'Contributions to the open-source world.',
    <comment> : <'disabled'> 
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error_code) {
      alert('Posting completed.');
    } else {
      alert('Error while posting.');
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: No, you can not disable that – of course the user is allowed to add a message to any link they share when you are using FB dialogs.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I know this isn't possible in case of facebook javascript SDK but was wondering if it possible in facebook android SDK. Do you have any idea to do so?